# Combined Probability of 5 Events with Different Probabilities and 25 Trials

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

I have 5 events, A through E, with individual probabilities:
P(A) = 0.12
P(B) = 0.05
P(C) = 0.11
P(D) = 0.12
P(E) = 0.60

After 25 trials here were the results:
A = 1 success
B = 3 successes
C = 4 successes
D = 2 successes
E = 15 successes

What is the combined probability that the results would turn out the way they did?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution

Comment: Thanks! I found a couple of calculators that were helpful. For my particular problem, the probability is 0.000612.